# No wlan - ath9k (network dialog is grayed out)

Tags: wifi

I'm using freya and had wlan without any problem since weeks/months.

Today I installed the printer driver for a Canon Pixma MG2950. Because I can't set up this printer for wireless printing in linux I started Win8 and set it up there with the cd rom from the printer.

In this setup there were a notice that the network is shutting down for a short time (or something like that)...

Don't know if this has something to do with my problem but since that time when I start freya again I see shortly after the desktop is there a bubble which states "the network gots shut down - offline".
When I click the WLAN icon all entries there are grayed out :(

(connecting a cable still works and I get a working connection)

Here are some debugging infos/outputs from my system http://pastebin.com/ihTej3VL

```
    ======== Wireless-Info START ========

System-Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

zinth-laptop 3.16.0-53-generic x86_64,  elementary OS Freya, freya

CPU    : AMD E1-2500 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics
Memory : 1438 MB
Uptime : 13:57:16 up 1 min,  2 users,  load average: 1,18, 0,67, 0,26


lspci ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:076b]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
--
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0632]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k


lsusb ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 064e:e330 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:07b2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


PCMCIA Card Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



iwconfig ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off



rfkill ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      Interface                 Soft blocked  Hard blocked
0: phy0: Wireless LAN               no            no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN      no            no
2: hci0: Bluetooth                  no            no


lsmod ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wl                   6367833  0 
acer_wmi               32522  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 acer_wmi
ath9k                 141379  0 
ath9k_common           25638  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              446521  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    29006  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              652777  1 ath9k
cfg80211              498458  5 wl,ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
wmi                    19193  1 acer_wmi
video                  20128  1 acer_wmi


module parameters ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

acer_wmi      (5): brightness=-1 | ec_raw_mode=N | force_series=0 | mailled=-1 | threeg=-1
ath9k         (6): blink=0 | bt_ant_diversity=0 | btcoex_enable=0 | nohwcrypt=0 | ps_enable=0 | use_chanctx=0
cfg80211      (2): cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz=N | ieee80211_regdom=00
mac80211      (5): beacon_loss_count=7 | ieee80211_default_rc_algo=minstrel_ht | max_nullfunc_tries=2 | max_probe_tries=5 | probe_wait_ms=500
video         (3): allow_duplicates=N | brightness_switch_enabled=Y | use_native_backlight=-1
wmi           (2): debug_dump_wdg=N | debug_event=N


nm-tool ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

State: disconnected
================o=============o========o=============o=========o===========o==============o===========
 Interface & ID | Type        | Driver | State       | Default | Speed     | Support      | HW Addr   
================o=============o========o=============o=========o===========o==============o===========
 wlan0          | 802.11 WiFi | ath9k  | unavailable | no      |           | WEP/WPA/WPA2 | 
----------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------
 eth0           | Wired       | alx    | unavailable | no      |           |              | 
----------------+-------------+--------+-------------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------


NetworkManager.state ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true


NetworkManager.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false


NM WiFi Profiles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

EasyBox-76D950       : ssid=EasyBox-76D950 | mac-address= | ipv4=auto | ipv6=auto 
FRITZ!Box 7272       : ssid=FRITZ!Box 7272 | mac-address= | ipv4=auto | ipv6=auto 
Linux                : ssid=Linux | mac-address= | ipv4=auto | ipv6=auto 
Zinth                : ssid=Zinth | mac-address= | ipv4=auto | ipv6=auto 


interfaces ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

resolv.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



Routes & Ping ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Kernel-IP-Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface


iw reg get ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

(Region : de_AT.UTF-8)
country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS


iwlist chan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 (2.412 GHz) - 13 (2.472 GHz)


iwlist scan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Waldmann"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000018e0a262704
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: 
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=26/70  Signal level=-84 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"allgaeudsl-mh"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000006192ebddbc
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: 
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"allgaeudsl-r"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000766934f900
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: 
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=24/70  Signal level=-86 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"allgaeudsl-rm"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000acf2e02d6c6
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: 
                    Channel:10
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-31 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Linux"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000012844f7d5d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: 
                    Channel:10
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Quality=34/70  Signal level=-76 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Linux"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000002e46e03f56a
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 07 - Address: 
                    Channel:10
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"allgaeudsl"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000cda5b3339
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago


blacklist ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma


modinfo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/extra/wl.ko
srcversion:     9A49255BA90267D99664757
depends:        cfg80211
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[acer_wmi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/acer-wmi.ko
srcversion:     97414F2256FC3B7919CD979
depends:        wmi,sparse-keymap,video
parm:           mailled:Set initial state of Mail LED (int)
parm:           brightness:Set initial LCD backlight brightness (int)
parm:           threeg:Set initial state of 3G hardware (int)
parm:           force_series:Force a different laptop series (int)
parm:           ec_raw_mode:Enable EC raw mode (bool)

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
srcversion:     CED1D76477A777795A07D73
depends:        ath9k_hw,mac80211,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
srcversion:     265A5990B1258ECC29235FC
depends:        cfg80211,ath9k_hw,ath

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
srcversion:     0D1161FC3B202FBE214F25D
depends:        ath

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
srcversion:     165C1DF76AF8C8B6A45DA4F
depends:        cfg80211

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
srcversion:     477882071593B10E01388C8
depends:        cfg80211
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
srcversion:     046346857FD53951C911443
depends:        
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[wmi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/wmi.ko
srcversion:     347CF30B94B5549A75865A8
depends:        
parm:           debug_event:Log WMI Events [0/1] (bool)
parm:           debug_dump_wdg:Dump available WMI interfaces [0/1] (bool)

[video]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/acpi/video.ko
srcversion:     2C29072BDC57BA9481E70D2
depends:        
parm:           brightness_switch_enabled:bool
parm:           allow_duplicates:bool
parm:           use_native_backlight:int


udev rules ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# PCI device 0x1969:0x10a1 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x168c:0x0036 (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"


Custom files/entries ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/etc/modules        : Default
/etc/rc.local       : Default
/etc/modprobe.d     : Not Default
/etc/pm/(cnf|pw|sl) : Default

[/etc/modprobe.d]
asus_nb_wmi.conf  : options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4
iwlwifi.conf      : remove iwlwifi \
                    (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
                    && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
mlx4.conf         : softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en
modesetting.conf  : options cirrus modeset=1
                    options mgag200 modeset=1


Kernel boot line ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-53-generic root=UUID=a88f5e9f-7602-4a4a-b8a9-4ce07b5e25e4 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7


dmesg ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[    0.044298] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.044327] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
[    2.542754] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 , Peter Oruba
[    2.543708] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    2.923429] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    2.966218] alx 0000:01:00.0 eth0: Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x Ethernet []
[    3.003568] [drm] Found VCE firmware/feedback version 40.2.2 / 15!
[    4.111637] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 3 (with firmware version 0x254f00)
[   21.528112] ath: phy0: WB335 1-ANT card detected
[   21.537009] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[   21.538629] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x42
[   21.538639] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x65
[   21.538642] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   21.538649] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   21.538651] ath: Regpair used: 0x65
[   22.300878] acer_wmi: Acer Laptop ACPI-WMI Extras
[   22.301134] acer_wmi: Function bitmap for Communication Button: 0x801
[   22.338549] acer_wmi: Brightness must be controlled by acpi video driver
[   22.382246] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   22.444026] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   22.500659] acer_wmi: Enabling Launch Manager failed: 0xe2 - 0x0
[   29.260630] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   31.049340] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

    ======== Done ========
```

Comment: Have you tried looking for the additional driver?

Comment: Is this a laptop? If so is the wifi hardware switch on?

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the driver

> sudo modprobe -v ath9k

and then restart the wireless network

> sudo service network-manager restart

If restarting the network manager didn't work, try rebooting the machine.